# A case of `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` I can't figure out why

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

***TL;DR:* A typical case of `all goroutines are asleep, deadlock!` but can't figure it out**

I'm parsing the Wiktionary XML dump to build a DB of words. I defer the parsing of each article's text to a goroutine hoping that it will speed up the process.
It's 7GB and is processed in under 2 minutes in my machine when doing it serially, but if I can take advantage of all cores, why not.

I'm new to threading in general, I'm getting a `all goroutines are asleep, deadlock!` error.
What's wrong here?

This may not be performant at all, as it uses an unbuffered channel, so all goroutines effectively end up executing serially, but my idea is to learn and understand threading and to benchmark how long it takes with different alternatives:

- unbuffered channel
- different sized buffered channel
- only calling as many goroutines at a time as there are `runtime.NumCPU()`

The summary of my code in pseudocode:

```
while tag := xml.getNextTag() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go parseTagText(chan, wg, tag.text)

    // consume a channel message if available
    select {
    case msg := <-chan:
        // do something with msg            
    default:
    }
}
// reading tags finished, wait for running goroutines, consume what's left on the channel
for msg := range chan {
    // do something with msg
}
// Sometimes this point is never reached, I get a deadlock
wg.Wait()

----

func parseTagText(chan, wg, tag.text) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // parse tag.text
    chan <- whatever // just inform that the text has been parsed
}
```

Complete code:
https://play.golang.org/p/0t2EqptJBXE

Comment: I think that the core problem is that no one is closing the channel, so your range loop is stuck after consuming all the data from the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your complete example on the Go Playground, you:

- Create a channel (line 39, `results := make(chan langs)`) and a wait-group (line 40, `var wait sync.WaitGroup`).  So far so good.
- Loop: in the loop, sometimes spin off a task:

  ```
              if ...various conditions... {
                  wait.Add(1)
                  go parseTerm(results, &wait, text)
              }
  ```
- In the loop, sometimes do a non-blocking read from the channel (as shown in your question).  No problem here either.  But...
- At the end of the loop, use:

  ```
  for res := range results {
      ...
  }
  ```

  *without* ever calling `close(results)` in exactly one place, after all writers finish.  This loop uses a *blocking* read from the channel.  As long as some writer goroutine is still running, the blocking read can block without having the whole system stop, but when the last writer finishes writing and exits, there are no remaining writer goroutines.  Any *other* remaining goroutines might rescue you, but there are none.

Since you use the `var wait` correctly (adding 1 in the right place, and calling `Done()` in the right place in the writer), the solution is to add one more goroutine, which will be the one to rescue you:

```
go func() {
    wait.Wait()
    close(results)
}()
```

You should spin off this rescuer goroutine just before entering the `for res := range results` loop.  (If you spin it off any earlier, it might see the `wait` variable count down to zero too soon, just before it gets counted up again by spinning off another `parseTerm`.)

This anonymous function will block in the `wait` variable's `Wait()` function until the last writer goroutine has called the final `wait.Done()`, which will unblock *this* goroutine.  Then this goroutine will call `close(results)`, which will arrange for the `for` loop in your `main` goroutine to finish, unblocking that goroutine.  When this goroutine (the rescuer) returns and thus terminates, there are no more rescuers, but we no longer need any.

(This main code then calls `wait.Wait()` unnecessarily:  Since the `for` didn't terminate until the `wait.Wait()` in the *new* goroutine already unblocked, we know that this next `wait.Wait()` will return immediately.  So we can drop this second call, although leaving it in is harmless.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nothing is closing the results channel, yet the range loop only exits when it closes. I've simplified your code to illustrate this and propsed a solution - basically consume the data in a goroutine:

```
// This is our producer
func foo(i int, ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- i
    fmt.Println(i, "done")
}
// This is our consumer - it uses a different WG to signal it's done
func consumeData(ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for x := range ch {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
    fmt.Println("ALL DONE")
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    // create the producers
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go foo(i, ch, &wg)
    }
    // create the consumer on a different goroutine, and sync using another WG
    consumeWg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    consumeWg.Add(1)
    go consumeData(ch,&consumeWg)

    wg.Wait()  // <<<< means that the producers are done
    close(ch) // << Signal the consumer to exit
    consumeWg.Wait() // << Wait for the consumer to exit
}
```